# Delphi LSP and Visual Studio Code: add file extensions to list of Delphi-type source files

Tags: delphi-11-alexandria

I have configured Visual Studio Code with DelphiLSP for Delphi code editing, and with `"*.pas"` files (lowercase extension), all works as expected (including syntax checking, hover help, Find Declaration). However, files with extension `"*.PAS"` (uppercase extension) do not have this functionality enabled.

Is there a configuration setting for DelphiLSP to allow more file extensions to be recognized?

This codebase was created decades ago in the 16-bit era, and many of the filenames are uppercase. The files are checked in to a version control system, and changing the case of the filenames is not a palatable option.